# writing to GPIO

Tags: gpio, python, usb, audio, led

Is there a way using python (Raspberry PI 4) to write a nibble to the GPIO in one write operation.

I have done a project which would benefit from that.

Project details here.

```
https://sites.google.com/view/fxv300/raspberry-pi-4
https://youtu.be/ybuxVGe1lxM
```

Answer (score 4):

No.

The hardware offers no support for such an operation.

What you can do is write 0 to a set of bits in one operation (clear bits) and write 1 to a set of bits in another operation (set bits). You can not set some bits and clear others in the same operation.

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library supports these functions.

[clear_bank_1](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#clear_bank_1)

[set_bank_1](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_bank_1)